# My own semaphore in java

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I'd like to implement my own semaphore in Java (just for practice, I am aware, that there is Semaphore class)
I have implemented it like that:

```
public class MySemaphore {
    private int value = 1;


    public synchronized void take() {
        this.value++;

        this.notify();
    }

    public synchronized void release(){


        while (this.value == 0) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        this.value--;
    }

}
```

I am trying to use it in such thread:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private static MySemaphore semaphore = new MySemaphore();
    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            semaphore.take();
            try {
                Main.myVariable += 1;
                semaphore.release();
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I start and join threads like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static int myVariable = 0;

    private static int threadsNumber = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Thread> allThreads = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < threadsNumber; i++) {
            allThreads.add(new Thread(new MyThread()));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < threadsNumber; i++) {
            allThreads.get(i).start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < threadsNumber; i++) {
            try{
                allThreads.get(i).join();
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("********************************");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Result is " + myVariable);

    }
}
```

I just want to increment a variable 10000 times and receive a result. Without semaphore the result is less than 10000 (like 9923, 9684), which is caused by non-atomicity of incrementation. I want to protect this variable using semaphore.
Unfortunately, the result is still less than or equal to 10000 (but much closer, in 9 out of 10 cases greater than 9990).
Do you have any idea why it happens? Is my semaphore wrong or am doing something wrong with launching threads?

Comment: It seems that you got the `take` and `release` mixed up. `take` (first operation) must wait, `release` must notify.

Comment: You're right, I swapped method names and that works, I just had good methods but with wrong names (and what follows, I used them improperly), thanks.

Comment: did you try using `AtomicInteger` ?

Answer (score -1):

In your MySemaphore class, value is already set to 1. It should be zero because in your release function you are verifying if value equals zero or not. This means that when your program starts, no thread will be able to have the semaphore(because you have set it to 1); doing so, they fall into waiting state. Your program ends when 'threadsNumber' reaches it's limit.In other words, you are not verifying if any thread is in waiting state before the programs ends. This explains why you have a 9/10 as success rate.

My recommendation would be to try setting the value to zero and also verify if there are any threads in waiting state.

Your code be like this:

```
public class MySemaphore {
  private int value = 0;  //this is already an error in your code

  public synchronized void take() {
    this.value++;
    this.notify(); // wakes up the first thread that called wait on the shared variable
  }

  public synchronized void release() throws InterruptedException{
    while(this.signals == 0) wait();
    this.value--;
  }

}
```

Comment: Try using `wait()`/`notify()` outside of `synchronized` block. Report the results.

Comment: I am using synchronized because operations that semaphore methods do are not atomic, I want to make them so.

Comment: What is the point to implement your own semaphore when you can simply use the synchronized keyword.